# Problemas a la hora de presentar el símbolo del Euro (€) en un CSV con Weblogic

Tags: java, tomcat, csv, codificación, weblogic

Tengo una aplicación en Java (JDK1.4) con servidor WebLogic. En local el desarrollo es con Tomcat (5.5), pero el despliegue se hace en WebLogic 8.1 (no nos queda otro remedio, cosas del cliente). Una de las operaciones que se realizan es generar un CSV y en él aparece el símbolo del euro (€). con el Tomcat no he tenido ningún problema, pero con WebLogic muestra una "?" en lugar del "€". Sin embargo usando en HTML estos mismos códigos, la presentación del símbolo es correcta. Sólo ocurre al generar el CSV. 
Investigando un poco he visto que hay varias formas/códigos de presentar este símbolo, y en esta tabla se ve el resultado de cada una en cada servidor:

[image: Tabla de codificación del símbolo del Euro y su representación en los servidores]

Sospecho que puede tener que ver con la codificación del servidor o del fichero CSV generado, pero no estoy seguro ni doy con la solución.

¿Alguna idea o sugerencia? Gracias

P.D: Ya sé que las versiones del software son muy antiguas, pero no podemos usar nada más moderno... Ya me gustaría :)

Comment: Yo usaría `\u20AC` por set utf 8. Adicional, aseguraría que el servidor y el fichero estén usando esta codificación, por lo menos para generar este archivo.

Comment: Esa prueba ya la he hecho, sin éxito en Weblogic...

Answer (score 2):

La solución me ha llegado por otra vía, así que la comparto por aquí.

El problema era que a la hora de generar el CSV no se estaba especificando ninguna codificación. Así que añadiendo esto a la cabecera del response...

```
//"res" es un HttpServletResponse
res.setContentType("text/csv; charset=ISO-8859-15");
```

... da como resultado que el comportamiento es el deseado en ambos servidores. Curiosamente me han recomendado usar ISO-8859-15, aclarándome que el ISO-8859-1 no incorpora el carácter del euro (€)

Comment: Nunca hay que dar por sentada la codificación en el servidor donde se ejecutan las cosas. Hay que ponerla explícita siempre!